# Failed to convert varchar '000.817' to int data type php

Tags: php, sql-server

I want first to show the values of variables in my table's rows then i will fix my traitment

for this I'm in this code now

```
<?php
  $serverName = "xxx.xx.xx.xxx";
  $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"PNE", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"sasa" );
  $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo );
  if( $conn === false ) {
      die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
  }

  $sql = "select Police,Produit from can";
  $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
  if( $stmt === false) {
      die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
  }


  while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    if ($row['Produit']== 'CHIMAC'){    
      $serverName = "xxx.xx.xx.xxx";
      $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"PDe", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"sasa" );
      $conndec = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo );
      if( $conndec === false ) {
         die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
      }
      $sqldec = "select produit_id,numeroPolice from Souscription s ,Produit p where p.id=s.produit_id and p.code='Prdconso' and s.numeroPolice='$row[Police]'";
      $stmtdec = sqlsrv_query( $conndec, $sqldec );
      if( $stmtdec === false) {
          die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
      }

      while( $rowdec = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmtdec, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
          if ($rowdec['numeroPolice']==$row['Police']){
              echo $rowdec['numeroPolice'].'<br>';

          }     
      }
    }       
  }
?>
```

I want to show my rows so I did this

`echo $rowdec['numeroPolice'];`

but it gives me this message

> Failed to convert varchar '000.817' to int data type

however my variable is varchar in my table and for this value in my table is `2345434`

I'm sorry for my bad english 
thanks

Comment: you really shouldn't be posting your ips here..

Comment: I feel like it's probably this `p.id=s.produit_id` What is the field type of both of those columns?

Comment: INT is whole number.. that's the reason why it failed.. change it to Float

Comment: p.id=s.produit_id are int

Comment: You really should start using ANSI-92 style joins. They have been around for more than 25 years now. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins And also you need to start using parameterized queries before bobby tables comes to visit. http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: seriously delete this post and try again, without the IP and sa user name and password. I'd change those immediately now that you have given the world the keys to your server.